# OSMnx: Divide a cache ox.graph into equal squares without redownloading each

Tags: python-3.x, osmnx

I am trying to divide a city into *n* squares.

Right now, I'm calculating the coordinates for all square centres and using the **ox.graph_from_point** function to extract the OSM data for each of them.

However, this is getting quite long at high *n* due to the API pausing times.

**My question:**

Is there a way to download all city data from OSM, and then divide the cache file into squares (using **ox.graph_from_point** or other) without making a request for each?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using OSMnx directly - no, there isn't. You would have to script your own solution using the existing tools OSMnx provides.